# strange behaviour of a function using 'jquery'

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, move

The function is relatively simple. When you click the button, an object will fall down. if you press the button again, the object go back to its random position and fall down again at the same speed.
but everytime I click the button, it (margin-top) gets much faster. I don't understand why?

*HTML*

```
<button id="fall" onclick="show_up()"> random-fall </button>
<div id="box" style="width:20px;height:20px;background:blue;">   </div>
```

*Script*

```
var top;

function show_up() {
        top = 0;
        $("#box").css("margin-top", top);
        var rand = Math.random() * 500;
        rand = parseInt(rand);

        $("#box").css("margin-left", rand);

        fall_out();
    }

function fall_out() {
        top++;
        if (top < 500) {
            $("#box").css("margin-top", top);
            window.setTimeout('fall_out()', 10);
        }
        else {
            top = 0;
            fall_out();

        }
}
```

Could anyone tell me the best way to solve it?

Comment: Isn't `fall_out` in an infinite loop? Regardless of the value of top, you are continuing to call `fall_out`.

Comment: Just a note: you should never pass strings to `setTimeout` (it uses `eval`).  You should pass functions.  `setTimeout(fall_out, 10);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that **`fall_out()` will never stop**. It'll go on calling itself. After reading your comment @ [Joop Eggen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8683473/403853) it seems to be desired behavior.

When you call **`show_up()` a second time**, `fall_out()` will be called again which results in **a second infinite loop**. That's the reason why your object is going to fall faster, `fall_out()` will be called more often than the first time (because of the 2 recursive loops).

**You must not call `fall_out()` in `show_up()` more than once.** You can e.g. set a variable like this (`started`):

```
var top;
var started = false; // fall_out() has not been called yet

function show_up() {
        top = 0;
        $("#box").css("margin-top", top);
        var rand = Math.random() * 500;
        rand = parseInt(rand);

        $("#box").css("margin-left", rand);

        if(!started){
            started = true; //going to start the endless recursion function
            fall_out();
        }            
}

function fall_out() {
        top++;
        if (top < 500) {
            $("#box").css("margin-top", top);
            window.setTimeout(fall_out, 10); //note that it's not nice to call setTimeout with a string as argument
        }
        else {
            top = 0;
            fall_out();

        }
}
```

Comment: great! it works perfectly..
I've got an another doubt. Can I also write this function with for-loop instead of if. If yes, then how can I slow down to see every steps?

Answer (score 1):

The last recursive call to **fall_out()** in the **else** branch should be removed, and margin-top set to 0. Otherwise recursion is endless.

Comment: That is if the box falls 500px down, the it will automatically calls the function again, start to fall.

Answer (score 0):

you are using random function. this script is just moving the box in random position in x-axis

Comment: that is just for the beginning.